# How can I locate my stolen Mac Book Air and Galaxy S4?

Tags: security

My car was broken in to, and both items have been stolen. I'm watching Dropbox, no activity. What else can I do?

Comment: Macbook Air may have "Find my Mac" enabled. Galaxy S4 may have Samsung's Find my Mobile enabled. If both are not enabled not much can be done. Contact the authorities and also both Apple and Samsung advise them of the serial number and they may be able to help. If you had lookout antivirus they do  track mobile phone location.

Comment: Also check android device manager.

Comment: Assuming you have a google account on your phone you can go to the android store and try to remotely install one of the 50 different locate my phone apps.  This may or may not work, but its worth a try.

Comment: Just start going to the gym and learn how to win a fight.

Answer (score 1):

For you **Macbook Air** you should definitely try to use "Find my Mac".

For **Android** I recommend you to remotely install [Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb&hl=en).

Also remember to change the passwords for the services you used on your phone. Don't do that for google account before installing the Plan B app.
If you are planning to remotelly wipe your phone remember that it could make the life of the thief easier since it will remove any lock password you have previosly set.

For a complete guide, check this nice post from [PC Magazine](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2423375,00.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try some local pawn shops, and craigslist, if I were you.